# MFC Open big document

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an Single-document Interface(SDI) Microsoft Foundation Class(MFC) app that has to load a big document file (takes about 2 minutes). For that reason, my app stays unresponsive while I am opening the document.

However, I would like my app to be responsive while opening the document. The problem is that, if I try to load my document on a thread, my `OnopenDocument` function (in my doc) will return before I actually open the document:

```
BOOL CmodguiDoc::OnOpenDocument(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
  if (!CDocument::OnOpenDocument(lpszPathName))
    return FALSE;
  start_tread(_open_doc); // just an example
  return TRUE; // Will return before the document will actually be open
}
```

How can I do this to be non-locking but only returning after the document is actually open? Or how can I at least make my app responsive while I am loading the document?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot hope for a thread to block and continue executing at the same time. Unless you buy one of those expensive quantum computers.

Comment: @IInspectable thats why I am asking for an alternative architecture

Comment: The alternative is to store the file name in your `OnOpenDocument` callback and load the data on demand. You cannot wait on your GUI thread for the load operation to run to completion and service other messages at the same time. You will have to return before the document is loaded, one way or another.

Comment: If your application is prepared to deal with reentrancy issues, you could also call [CWinThread::PumpMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1tkd768.aspx) periodically from your document loader, to service messages on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 7):

Returning after the thread has been created is OK. You should define a state for the document such as `loading` and `loaded`. When you start the thread the state should be `loading`. The view(s) should look at the state and display accordingly. When the thread has finished loading the document it should post a message to the document. In the handler, set the state to `loaded` and call `UpdateAllViews()` to give the views the chance to update with the new document data.

Example: This will print "loading" while the doc is loading and "loaded" and loaded after it finished in the view.

[image]

In resource.h:

```
#define IDD_NotifyDocumentFinished        101
```

In the document header:

```
public:
   enum DocState
   {
      None,
      Failed,
      Loading,
      Loaded
   };

   DocState GetDocState() const {return m_state;}
private:
   DocState m_state;
   void StartLoading();
```

In the document implementation:

```
BOOL CMFCDocViewAsyncDoc::OnOpenDocument(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
   if(!CDocument::OnOpenDocument(lpszPathName))
      return FALSE;   

   m_state = Loading;

   StartLoading();

   return TRUE;
}

UINT LongRunningFunction(LPVOID param)
{
   Sleep(3000);

   HWND hWnd = AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd();

   NMHDR hdr = {hWnd, IDD_NotifyDocumentFinished, 0};
   ::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NOTIFY, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&hdr));

   return 0;
}

void CMFCDocViewAsyncDoc::StartLoading()
{
   AfxBeginThread(&LongRunningFunction, nullptr);
}

BOOL CMFCDocViewAsyncDoc::OnCmdMsg(UINT nID, int nCode, void* pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO* pHandlerInfo)
{
   if(HIWORD(nCode) == WM_NOTIFY)
   {
      WORD wCode = LOWORD(nCode);
      AFX_NOTIFY * notify = reinterpret_cast<AFX_NOTIFY*>(pExtra);
      if(notify->pNMHDR->idFrom == IDD_NotifyDocumentFinished)
      {
         m_state = Loaded;
         UpdateAllViews(nullptr);
      }
   }

   return TRUE;
}
```

In the view:

```
void CMFCDocViewAsyncView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CMFCDocViewAsyncDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    CMFCDocViewAsyncDoc::DocState state = pDoc->GetDocState();
   CString sstate;
   switch(state)
   {
   case CMFCDocViewAsyncDoc::None:
      sstate = "None";
      break;
   case CMFCDocViewAsyncDoc::Failed:
      sstate = "Failed";
      break;
   case CMFCDocViewAsyncDoc::Loading:
      sstate = "Loading";
      break;
   case CMFCDocViewAsyncDoc::Loaded:
      sstate = "Loaded";
      break;
   }
   pDC->TextOut(50, 50, sstate);
}
```

Update: Also look here for a similar, more detailed example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14706/Notifying-the-Document.

Comment: Thank you, but could you be more specific? how do I define document states?

Comment: And there's yet another problem. I cannot get the document handle from the thread, wo I cant update the state from the thread

Comment: Not from the thread, but in the handler for the message posted by the thread when it has finished.

Comment: Another question, when is the document data set? e.g. the window title with the project name?

Answer (score 1):

When it takes two minutes to just load something, then there are two reasons for that:

1. You are doing something stupid while loading, like e.g. running expensive algorithms on the data like indexing or graphical rendering. If you store the data in containers, the overhead of allocations could also become significant. If that is the case, only perform them on demand or perform these operations asynchronously in the background. You can notify the main thread (the one running the UI) when done in order to display the rendered graphics, for example.
2. The data is incredibly large. In that case, you will have to rethink how to access this data anyway, because any operation might be expensive. Your best bet will be to use an asynchronous model, like sending a request to the model to perform some operation. The model then sends a response to the UI to display the data. In that case, you need to think about how to make this transparent to the user though. One approach is to darken the display area after a change request and only brighten it up after the response or a progress bar.

Comment: My project file consists of a unique file that can grow up to 2gb